# Mixed types in an Array gson [java]

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, gson

I want to parse the following json. Everything works find except the args part. The gson looks like:
**my.json**

```
{
"daily":[
    {
    "type":"anystring",
    "set":[0,0,"anystring"],
    "args":[[0,1,"String"],[1,1,"String"]]
    },
    {
    "type":"anystring",
    "set":[0,0,"anystring"],
    "args":[[0,0,"anystring"],1,2,3]
    }
]}
```

**My code looks like:**

```
public class ReadJSON {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Daily data = gson.fromJson(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my.json")), new TypeToken<Daily>() {}.getType());
        System.out.println(data);

    }
}


public class Daily {
    public List<DailyRule> daily;

    public List <DailyRule>getDaily(){
        return daily;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return daily.toString();
    }
}


public class DailyRule {
    public String type;
    public List<String> set = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String[]> args;

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public String getOp(){
        return op;
    }

    public String getCond(){
        return cond;
    }

    public List<String> getSet(){
        return set;
    }

    public List<String[]> getArgs() {
        return args;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return type+" "+set.toString()+" "+args.toString();
    }
}
```

it throws me an error like  Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line... 
Well I understand why the error is thrown but not how to fix it. I cannot change the json file (which would be probably the easiest solution). Are there easier solutions out there instead of using a serializer? How would I implement it? I hate being a noob :/ Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `[[0,1,"String"],[1,1,"String"],` a typo or is your JSON malformed?

Comment: Your json is malformed...Validate your json using http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist multiple errors in your code. First

1) cond and op is not declared in DailyRule class.

```
String op;
String cond;
```

2) As you are inserting sometimes Array,other time integer to args, it must be List of args must be of type that can support any data type.
So

```
public List<Object> args;
```

So your daily route class must look like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DailyRule {
public String type;
public List<String> set = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<Object> args;
String op;
String cond;

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public String getOp(){
    return op;
}

public String getCond(){
    return cond;
}

public List<String> getSet(){
    return set;
}
public List<Object> getArgs() {
    return args;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
   return type+" "+set.toString()+" "+args.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: public List<Object> args;

that's it! Thanks mate